# Static method mocked via EasyMock and Powermock getting invoked when calling EasyMock.expect()

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, easymock, powermock

I am using TestNG, EasyMock and PowerMock for testing. As per the code below I am trying to mock a static method that is called from the static method under test (fetchAuthenticator). When I run the test, the executeHttpGet method gets executed when calling EasyMock.expect.

```
@PrepareForTest(Metadata.class)
public class MetadataTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
@Test
public void testPatience(){
PowerMock.mockStatic(HttpHelper.class);
EasyMock.expect(
    HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(EasyMock.anyString()))
    .andReturn(
        "{\"response\":\"some_value\"}");
PowerMock.replay(HttpHelper.class);

String response = Whitebox.invokeMethod(Metadata.class,
    "fetchAuthenticator",
    "something-else",
    "somesite.com", "another-value");
assertNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

I found similar questions, but no answers.
[EasyMock: Actual function gets called while passing as an argument to EasyMock.expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084887/easymock-actual-function-gets-called-while-passing-as-an-argument-to-easymock-e)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Actually better is to use Mockito.

Comment: Why is the method being invoked when it is not expected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

at the class-level of the test case

and replace

```
@PrepareForTest(Metadata.class)
```

with

```
@PrepareForTest({ AuthenticationMetadata.class, HttpHelper.class })
```

Comment: I am using testNG, not junit. But I fixed it by adding @PrepareForTest({ AuthenticationMetadata.class, HttpHelper.class })

Comment: Where on earth did `AuthenticationMetadata` come from?!